# Can't find path when build project in vue3

Tags: node.js, vue.js, build, path, vue-router

When I build the project and run it, The first page can run properly and the redirect is working but when I change the path it show ***Can't get /admin(path name)*** it's seems like I can't direct by typing the URL.

It's work fine when I run serve.

Here is my router index.js

```
import Blog from "../views/Blog.vue";
import Admin from "../views/Admin.vue";

const routes = [
{ path: "/", redirect: "/blog" },
{ path: "/blog",name: "blog",component: Blog },
{ path: "/admin", name: "admin", component: Admin },
]
const router = createRouter({ 
      history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL), routes,
});

export default router;
```

Comment: More details please! What does your file directory look like

Comment: pretend we know nothing about your app (because we don't).  how did you set things up?  whats your router.js file look like?  include code snippets where you think the problem might be

Comment: here is my router @yoduh